# Xamarin.Android remove activity from history depending on user's action

Tags: android, xamarin.android

I need to remove some screens from the navigation stack depending on what button is pressed.

I have a Home screen and next to it there are 3 more screens where the user enters some data(let's call them S1,S2, S3).

S1 is opened from home, S2 from S1, S3 from S2.

Each of these 3 screens have a back and a next button.

If the current screen is S2 and I press the back button I would like to remove it from the navigation stack, otherwhise when I go back to S1 and I press the back button it will go to S2, which is wrong, it should go to home.

I found out that calling `Finish()` would do the work, but it is not working if I press the next button instead of back. Neither the `NoHistory = true` is working in this case.

Is there something that can manage this or do you have any idea to solve it?

Comment: What did you do when press a "next button"?

Comment: I press the "next button" to go to the next screen like this: Home->S1->S2->S3->Home. After getting to the home screen again and I press "back" it should not go to S3, these 3 screens should be removed from the navigation stack

Comment: When your screen is `S2`, when press the back button you could calling `Finish()` to remove it from the stack, when press the next button you could use `StartActivity(typeof(S3))`  to open S3.

Comment: @YorkShen-MSFT It works, thank you! I didn't think it would be that easy. You should post it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When your screen is `S2`, when press the back button you could calling `Finish()` to remove it from the stack, when press the next button you could use `StartActivity(typeof(S3))` to open `S3`.

Comment: @Madalin Sisu, I have update my answer, please check it.

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 solutions there :

1) You can override the OnBackPressed method on your activity. This will erase the classic behavior of the back button. So, for example in S2, you can override your OnBackPressed in order to navigate explicitly to S1. But be careful with that, because in this case you should also override the OnBackPressed method of S1 in order to avoid going back to S2 when the back button is pressed.

You can override OnBackPressed on your activity this way :

```
 public override void OnBackPressed()
    {
        //navigate to the screen you want to
    }
```

2) You can also set, in your activity, `NoHistory = true`. In your question, you said that the `NoHistory = false` statement does not work for you, which is perfectly normal since you have to put it **true** if you don't want the activity in your history stack.

Hope it helped !

Comment: Sorry, I meant `NoHistory = true`. But this does not work because I don't know what button will be pressed.

Comment: Well, I remember I faced the same problem and I still have the code to solve the problem, but this is something quite complex (I was working with NavigationParameter and so on, because now I remember than NoHistory = true did not work for me neither.

Unfortunately I'm quite busy right now but I'll try to help you whenever possible